# How to have the `INamingConvention` passed into a custom value converter?

Tags: c#, yamldotnet

I wrote a custom value converter for YamlDotNet. I initialize it like this:

```cs
var ser = new SerializerBuilder().WithNamingConvention(UnderscoredNamingConvention.Instance).WithTypeConverter(MyTypeConverter.Instance).Build();
```

How to get the naming convention into the `MyTypeConverter` without having to explicitly pass it e.g. via a constructor parameter?